# How to get element within the parent div by class?

Tags: jquery

I want to grab `Text to grab` below:

```
<div class="article-box">                    
    <div>
        <a href="/someurl" class="article-text">Text to grab</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <a href="/anotherurl" class="q-author">The author</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <ul class="share-buttons pull-left">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="tw-share">Share on facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="tw-share">Tweet it</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="article-box">
    //similar to above
</div>
```

My jquery is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".tw-share").click(function() {
      var article = $(this).parent(".article-text" ); //<--Here is the Problem
      console.log('article is: ', article);
      var aurl= window.location.href; 
        window.location='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + article + '&url='+aurl;

    });
});
```

But it fails. How can I fix it?

Comment: It's **well worth** your time to read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It only takes an hour or two, and pays you that time back *immediately*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that `.tw-share` is not a child of `.article` text. It's a child of a sibling. To fix this you could use `closest()` to get the containing `.article-box`, then `find()`.

I would also strongly suggest you call `encodeURIComponent()` on the text you're placing in the URL to ensure that it's encoded correctly, and doesn't inferfere with the URL you're adding in to. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  jQuery(".tw-share").click(function() {
    var $article = $(this).closest('.article-box').find(".article-text");
    var articleText = encodeURIComponent($article.text());
    var aurl = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);     
    var url = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + articleText + '&url=' + aurl;
    
    console.log('article is: ', articleText);  
    console.log(url);
    
    //window.location = url;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article-box">
  <div>
    <a href="/someurl" class="article-text">Text to grab</a>
  </div><br>
  <div>
    <a href="/anotherurl" class="q-author">The author</a>
  </div><br>
  <ul class="share-buttons pull-left">
    <li><a href="#" class="tw-share">Share on facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tw-share">Tweet it</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="article-box">
  <div>
    <a href="/someurl" class="article-text">Text to grab #2</a>
  </div><br>
  <div>
    <a href="/anotherurl" class="q-author">The author #2</a>
  </div><br>
  <ul class="share-buttons pull-left">
    <li><a href="#" class="tw-share">Share on facebook #2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tw-share">Tweet it #2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need traverse up to a common parent element i.e. `article-box` using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) then use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to target the `article-text` element. Additionaly [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) needs to be used to get the element's text.

```
var article = $(this).closest('.article-box').find(".article-text" ).text();
```